# how to set the postion for UILabel in Different UIOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view and I am creating a UILabel programatically and calling it my parameter passing as I need many UILabel text with Different Position frame, so I am calling it by parameter passing.

Using the code below, when I rotate to landscape mode the portrait view Label still appears. How do I overcome this? I need to be done in the below code. I want the position of the Label frame to be changed from portrait view to landscape view.

NOTE:I need to Create many Label,s around 15 to 20, so I am using parameter passing, so that I don't need to write as many methods for creating each label.

```
-(UILabel*)createLabel:(CGRect)frame :(NSString*)labelTitle
{
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
    myLabel.text = labelTitle;     
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

{ 
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(450,140,60,20):@"Ratings:"]];  
        [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(450,170,60,20):@"Reviews:"]];  
    }
    else
    {
        [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(650,140,60,20):@"Ratings:"]];
        [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(650,170,60,20):@"Reviews:"]];  
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create them in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, because it will get called everytime the orientation changes, thus creating more labels.

Instead create them once in `- (void) loadView`, and give them the correct *autoResizingMask* properties, e.g:

```
myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;
```

This will cause the desired behaviour when the orientation changes: the labels will automatically resize and the whole turning animation will be smooth.

PS: Mind that the way you were creating Labels is causing a memory leak, use the `release` method to prevent this.

Comment: i tried the following code in ViewDidLoad method
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(600,140,60,20);
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
    myLabel.text = LabelTitle; 
but it shows undeclared LabelTitle how to assign labeltitle when calling the below -(BOOL)shouldAutorot
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {      
        myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(600,140,60,20);
        myLabel.text = @"Ratings:";
    }
    else

Comment: Thats because you sent the LabelTitle as a parameter to the createLabel method, you cannot access it if you don't pass it. Instead you could use myLabel.text = @"<your title here>"

Comment: i wrote myLabel.text = @"Ratings"; and calling the following code  shown next in (BOOL)ShouldnautoRotate method but still its working its throwing exception
(BOOL)ShouldnautoRotate{
 myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(600,140,60,20);  
        myLabel.text = @"Ratings:";

Comment: Please, read my first awnser and do it from that method. or /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

The label for portrait orientation still appears because each time the device is rotated, you are adding a new label without removing the old one.

I think it is not a good idea to create new labels while you can just change the frame of the existing ones. To do this, you should add two properties (say reviewLabel and ratingLabel) to your class and assign your labels to these when they are first created. Then on your shouldAutorotate function, you can access these labels and change their frame.

Comment: can i have a sample code..as i am new to iphone development..And one more question is i need to create many Labels  around 15 so do i need to have properties for all the labels...?

Comment: If you have that many labels, having a property for each one of them is not very practical. Try to lay them out properly by setting their autoresizingMask as Wolfert suggested. You can also use view tags. Set each label's tag like `myLabel.tag = 10` on creation and retrieve the labels on shouldAutorotate function by using `myLabel = [self.view viewWithTag:10]`.